# How to clean up duplicate entries from one of column

Tags: mysql

I have one column in the table whose values are stored with NEW LINE delimeter. I want to clean up the duplicate entries from that column.

Table structures i am writing below

Example:  Table Name  : STUDENT

```
 ID    SUBJECT
---------------
1      English
       HINDI
       FRENCH
       ENGLISH
       FRENCH
```

I want mysql script which will give the result like this for me

```
 ID    SUBJECT
---------------
1      English
       HINDI
       FRENCH
```

Comment: Now We are not allowing to change any design  structure. I need some mysql script which reads the existing column data and deletes the duplicate entries from that column and update the column without duplicate entries.

Comment: What have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Share your findings.

Answer (score 1):

This is bad DB design. Use another table to store the subjects of students:

```
students table      example content
--------------      ---------------
id                  1
name                peter
...

subjects
--------
id                  1
name                english


student_subjects
----------------
student_id          1
subject_id          1
```

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the reply..  Design done by someone else. Now we are just enhancing this to remove the duplicate entries .

Comment: And use the primary keys. In students table the primary key is the id, in subjects idem, and in student_subjects the primary key is (student_id, subject_id) so it will prevent having duplicate entries.

Comment: Now We are not allowing to change any design  structure. I need some mysql script which reads the existing column data and deletes the duplicate entries from that column and update the column without duplicate entries.

Comment: Good luck with that. It will be a real pain.

Comment: Any suggestion how can i achieve that?

Comment: Use at least a comma seperated list instead of newline seperated (use `replace()` for that). Then you can use [`find_in_set()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).